# UI Bootstrap tabset show the content right to the tabs

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

first of all: i'm totally new at bootstrap. I want to use the [vertical tabset](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) to display the content right to the tabs. sketch of my idea:

[image: Hand sketch of idea]

```
<tabset vertical="true" type="tabs">
<tab heading="Vertical 1">Vertical content 1</tab>
<tab heading="Vertical 2">Vertical content 2</tab>
</tabset>
```

but unfortunately I didn't make it to solve this this css commands.

Comment: I inserted your image for you. Also, no need to put thanks you's in the question.

Answer (score 0):

sexy picture :D

```
<div class="col-xs-3"> <!-- required for floating -->
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left"><!-- 'tabs-right' for right tabs -->
 <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
 <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
 <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-9">
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home Tab.</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile Tab.</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Messages Tab.</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings Tab.</div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://dbtek.github.io/bootstrap-vertical-tabs/learn.html

Answer (score 0):

1.download css from link : http://dbtek.github.io/bootstrap-vertical-tabs/
2.Add it to your page and design page as below :

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-3"> <!-- required for floating -->
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left"><!-- 'tabs-right' for right tabs -->
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home Tab.</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile Tab.</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Messages Tab.</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings Tab.</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```